# How to loop over inputs for a general amount of inputs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, eval

I have a (K x KM) matrix, `A`, where the first (K x K) elements of the matrix, `A_1`, is the first argument of a function, and the last M (K x K) elements, `A_M`, is the last input into the function.

`M` is arbitrary and determined by the size on matrix `A`.

What I need is code for MATLAB that evaluates:

```
blkdiag(A_1,A_2,...,A_M)
```

I've thought about using a loop of `sprintf` and `eval`, but that seems inefficient. One efficient solution I've found is:

```
B = kron(ones(1,M),A')
for ii=1:size(B,1)
  for jj=1:size(B,2)
    if ii+jj in off diagonal block
      B(ii,jj)=0;
    end
  end
end
```

But I'd like something where I don't need to figure out the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution

```
B = kron(speye(M),ones(K));
B(logical(B)) = A;
```

Comment: Nice! You actually don't need the `(:)` after `A`, though.

Comment: Also, a code-golf trick (which is not very readable, so I only use it for code-golf): `B(~~B)=A` ;)

Comment: Why the sparse matrix instead of full?

Comment: @hipHopMetropolisHastings If size of B is so large, sparse matrix can overcome memory limits and/or speed up creating the diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to collect your individual matrices into separate cells of a cell array using [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html), then pass them to [`blkdiag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html) as a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
>> A = rand(3, 9)

A =

    0.6892    0.0838    0.1524    0.9961    0.1067    0.7749    0.0844    0.8001    0.1818
    0.7482    0.2290    0.8258    0.0782    0.9619    0.8173    0.3998    0.4314    0.2638
    0.4505    0.9133    0.5383    0.4427    0.0046    0.8687    0.2599    0.9106    0.1455

>> [r, c] = size(A);
>> B = mat2cell(A, r, r.*ones(1, c/r));
>> B = blkdiag(B{:})

B =

    0.6892    0.0838    0.1524         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.7482    0.2290    0.8258         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.4505    0.9133    0.5383         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0    0.9961    0.1067    0.7749         0         0         0
         0         0         0    0.0782    0.9619    0.8173         0         0         0
         0         0         0    0.4427    0.0046    0.8687         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0844    0.8001    0.1818
         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.3998    0.4314    0.2638
         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2599    0.9106    0.1455
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me on the coding chops! Was thinking of a way to do that.